# Can we install Microsoft TFS 2013 without Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

Is it mandatory to install Sharepoint Foundation 2013 for installting Microsoft TFS?

http://www.alexandervanwynsberghe.be/installing-tfs-2013-on-windows-server-2012-r2-and-sql-server-2014-ctp1/

Answer (score 0):

No, Sharepoint is not mandatory.